# I am getting these errors while compiling

Tags: android

```
package com.prgguru.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;
import com.loopj.android.http.ResponseHandlerInterface;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
    //DB Class to perform DB related operations
    DBController controller = new DBController(this);
    //Progress Dialog Object
    ProgressDialog prgDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Get User records from SQLite DB 
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList =  controller.getAllUsers();
        //
        if(userList.size()!=0){
            //Set the User Array list in ListView
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter( MainActivity.this,userList, R.layout.view_user_entry, new String[] { "userId","userName"}, new int[] {R.id.userId, R.id.userName});
            ListView myList=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
            myList.setAdapter(adapter);
            //Display Sync status of SQLite DB
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), controller.getSyncStatus(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        //Initialize Progress Dialog properties
        prgDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        prgDialog.setMessage("Synching SQLite Data with Remote MySQL DB. Please wait...");
        prgDialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        //When Sync action button is clicked
        if (id == R.id.refresh) {
            //Sync SQLite DB data to remote MySQL DB
            syncSQLiteMySQLDB();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    //Add User method getting called on clicking (+) button
    public void addUser(View view) {
        Intent objIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewUser.class);
        startActivity(objIntent);
    }

    public void syncSQLiteMySQLDB(){
        //Create AsycHttpClient object
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList =  controller.getAllUsers();
        if(userList.size()!=0){
            if(controller.dbSyncCount() != 0){
                prgDialog.show();
                params.put("usersJSON", controller.composeJSONfromSQLite());
                client.post("http://192.168.65.1/sqlitemysqlsync/insertuser.php",params ,new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                  @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String response) {
                        System.out.println(response);
                        prgDialog.hide();
                        try {
                            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);
                            System.out.println(arr.length());
                            for(int i=0; i<arr.length();i++){
                                JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)arr.get(i);
                                System.out.println(obj.get("id"));
                                System.out.println(obj.get("status"));
                                controller.updateSyncStatus(obj.get("id").toString(),obj.get("status").toString());
                            }
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DB Sync completed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Occured [Server's JSON response might be invalid]!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                  @Override
                    public String getCharset() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return super.getCharset();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Header[] getRequestHeaders() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return super.getRequestHeaders();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public URI getRequestURI() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return super.getRequestURI();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean getUseSynchronousMode() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return super.getUseSynchronousMode();
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void handleMessage(Message arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.handleMessage(arg0);
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected Message obtainMessage(int responseMessageId,
                            Object responseMessageData) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return super.obtainMessage(responseMessageId, responseMessageData);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.onCancel();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.onFinish();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPostProcessResponse(
                            ResponseHandlerInterface instance,
                            HttpResponse response) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.onPostProcessResponse(instance, response);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPreProcessResponse(
                            ResponseHandlerInterface instance,
                            HttpResponse response) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.onPreProcessResponse(instance, response);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(int bytesWritten, int totalSize) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.onProgress(bytesWritten, totalSize);
                    }

                    //@Override
                    public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.onRetry(retryNo);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStart() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.onStart();
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void postRunnable(Runnable runnable) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.postRunnable(runnable);
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void sendMessage(Message msg) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.sendMessage(msg);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void sendResponseMessage(HttpResponse arg0)
                            throws IOException {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.sendResponseMessage(arg0);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void setCharset(String charset) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.setCharset(charset);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void setRequestHeaders(Header[] requestHeaders) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.setRequestHeaders(requestHeaders);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void setRequestURI(URI requestURI) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.setRequestURI(requestURI);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void setUseSynchronousMode(boolean sync) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.setUseSynchronousMode(sync);
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return super.clone();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean equals(Object o) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return super.equals(o);
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.finalize();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int hashCode() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return super.hashCode();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String toString() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return super.toString();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error,
                        String content){
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        prgDialog.hide();
                        if(statusCode == 404){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Requested resource not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }else if(statusCode == 500){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong at server end", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unexpected Error occcured! [Most common Error: Device might not be connected to Internet]", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int arg0, Header[] arg1, byte[] arg2,
                            Throwable arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                @Override
                    public void onSuccess(int arg0, Header[] arg1, byte[] arg2) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SQLite and Remote MySQL DBs are in Sync!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No data in SQLite DB, please do enter User name to perform Sync action", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

The errors during compiling are:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type The method onSuccess(String)
>   of type new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){} must override or implement a
>   supertype method
>
> The method onFailure(int, Throwable, String) of type new
>   AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){} must override or implement a supertype
>   method

Please help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, you need to define the methods onSuccess and onFailure using different signature. Check which version of the library you are using but shoudn't it be something like this?

```
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
         // Successfully got a response
     }

     @Override
     public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[]     responseBody, Throwable error) {
         // Response failed :(
     }
```

Comment: I am referring to a website which helps in syncing to database.
I am new to Android. And the version I am using is android-async-http-1.4.6.
The link: http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-sync-sqlite-on-android-to-mysql-db/

Comment: The library has changed the signatures. You need to either downgrade the library to an old version (not recommended) or change the signature in your code (better solution). The library v 1.2.0 is using the signature you are referring to - downloadable [here](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/tree/master/releases)

Answer (score 1):

You don't respect the original class method prototypes

[onSuccess](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpResponseHandler.html#onSuccess(int,%20org.apache.http.Header[],%20byte[])):

```
onSuccess(int statusCode, org.apache.http.Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody)
```

[onFailure](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpResponseHandler.html#onFailure(int,%20org.apache.http.Header[],%20byte[],%20java.lang.Throwable)):

```
onFailure(int statusCode, org.apache.http.Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, java.lang.Throwable error)
```